# layer thickness calculation complex segmentation

Tags: python, image, analysis, imagej

Im currently working on measuring the layer of an image from OCT in image J. However Im encountering troubles with the segmentation. I am originally working on Image J to create a macro. However I want to know if there is a way easier or feasible in Python to calculate the mean thickness between the layers or lines marked on the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHT1P.jpg)
The original image is found under this link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1db_o2BgeTP03cXrcTz9RWu7DEapqQee5?usp=sharing

My idea is to make this process automated. If someone know about other post similar I would appreciate if you can share them or help me.

Im expecting to calculate the mean thickness of the layer on top of the bright line along the whole image width.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve has been posted by you to the Image.sc Forum several times already and of course the solution is a mathematically one. Therefore, it is independent of the programming language you use. ImageJ surely is a rather universal framework for image processing and if you don't succeed with ImageJ, it is rather unlikely that you will succeed with any other language or image processing framework.

Answer (score 0):

Two results from an attempt using the ImageJ-plugin "Easy_EdgeTrace" for both traces:
[image]
[image]

Two results from an attempt using the ImageJ-plugin "Easy_EdgeTrace" for the top trace and linear regression of maxima for the bottom trace:
[image]
[image]